# Override part of text file

Tags: c, io, overriding

Text File:

```
line_1: abcdefg
```

override the first k chars to ttttt so that the new text file is:

```
line_1: tttttfg
```

I used `fprintf` and when opening the .txt file I used `w+` flag, however it will erase the whole `.txt` file and not just override the first `bytes_number` characters.

I tried many things that didn't seem to wok. Any hints would be thankful!
Thanks in advance!

```
void my_write (char* path, int bytes_number, char* flag, char* data, int sockfd)
{
    FILE* fp;
    char* test;
    int n, i;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    if (bytes_number > 1000 || bytes_number < 0)
    {
        write (sockfd, "Failure", strlen("Failure"));
        return;
    }
    test = data;
    if (strlen(test) < bytes_number)
    {
        write (sockfd, "Failure", strlen("Failure"));
        return;
    }
    if (!strcmp(flag, "override"))
    {
        fp = fopen(path, "w+"); /* Open file with flag 'w' so that we overrun the data */
        if (fp == NULL) { /* File doesn't exist, invalid path*/
            write (sockfd, "Failure", strlen("Failure"));
            return;
        }
        **i = fprintf (fp, "%.*s\n", bytes_number, data);**
        if (i < 0)
            write (sockfd, "Failure", strlen("Failure"));
        else
            write (sockfd, "Write Success", strlen("Write Success"));
    }
    else if (!strcmp(flag, "append"))
    {
        fp = fopen(path, "ab"); /* Open file with flag 'ab' so that we don't override data while writing */
        if (fp == NULL) /* File doesn't exist, invalid path*/
            write (sockfd, "Failure", strlen("Failure"));
            i = fprintf (fp, "%.*s\n", bytes_number, data);
        if (i < 0)
            write (sockfd, "Failure", strlen("Failure"));
        else
            write (sockfd, "Write Success", strlen("Write Success"));
    }
    else {
        write (sockfd, "Failure", strlen("Failure"));
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read and overwrite text file in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188053/how-to-read-and-overwrite-text-file-in-c)

Comment: @Simon in my case the number of characters is unknown, the other lad only wants to change the first char of each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fopen(path,"w+")` opens a file for write and update, deleting the file first if it already exists. To avoid deleting the file first, one can use `fopen(path,"r+")` to open it for reading and update.

If the aim is just to replace the specified characters, then the `\n` at the end of the `fprintf` format string should be omitted, so that the line reads `i = fprintf (fp, "%.*s", bytes_number, data)`.

Comment: I tried "r+" flag, it does overrite the first K characters, however it then deletes 2 characters and the rest are in a seperated line.

Any idea how to fix that ?

Comment: @TonyTannous: I think you'll find that the problem is the newline character in the `fprintf` format, and I expect you are using a Windows computer where the newline character is automatically expanded by C into two characters - carriage return followed by a newline - thus two extra characters are deleted and the following text continues on the next line of the text file.

Comment: Most probably, I'm on windows 7, however the file is compiled and run on a VS using VMware, and the output.txt is on my laptop (which is run on windows7).
I am using google to find a way to omit the \n. Thank you!

Comment: @TonyTannous: As far as I can see, you should just be able to take the "\n" out of the string. Unless I'm missing something, I don't see why you would need it.